# Anylogic: Queue decision making of Agents

Tags: agent, anylogic, multimethod

I am working on a model for my thesis about attraction visiting decision-making of tourists in Anylogic. How can I give the visitors (agents) varying maximum waiting times. So that if a queue of an attraction exceeds this waiting time, the visitor won't go to its most preferred attraction but to its second most preferred attraction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly. 
But if I did you can create a parameter inside the agent called: MaxWaitTime and use the tool ChooseProbabilityDistribution to generate the value of MaxWaitTime. 
Then, while in the queue you have to make a code to check if current waiting time >= MaxWaitTime and if yes, the agent will go to another place.

[image]